# Grails domain class behaves unexpectedly when overriding implicit getter

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

Consider the following grails domain class:

**Test.groovy**

```
package test

class Test {    
    Integer month
    Integer year
    String performancePeriod = ""

    static constraints = {      
        month(range:01..12, nullable:true)
        year(range:2010..2020, nullable:false)
        performancePeriod(nullable:true)        
    }

    String getPerformancePeriod() {
        if(month) {
            "${month?.toString().padLeft(2,'0')}.${year?.toString()}"
        }
        else {
            getYearStringFormat()
        }
    }

    String getPerformancePeriodDate(){
        return new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1).time
    }

    String getJahrStringFormat() {
        year ? year.toString() : ""
    }

    String getMonatZweiStellig() {
        month? month.toString().padLeft(2,'0') : ""
    }   
}
```

It is legacy code. I know the design is bad, since presentation logic is bound to the domain object. By presentation logic I mean the property `performancePeriod`, which only purpose is to deliver a String format of year and date for presentation.

Now, generate the controller and scaffold the views. If you create a new `Test` record without setting `performancePeriod`, the property will be set implicitly using the logic given in the method `getPerformancePeriod`.

I cannot understand this behaviour. I know the design is bad in the first place, especially because of the functional dependency `{year, month} -> performancePeriod`, but when is it `performancePeriod` saved to the database? Why can't I decide to have it null until I decide to set a value?

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I decide to have it null until I decide to set a value?

You can.  When the persistence engine persists your object it has to interrogate the object to retrieve the values of the specific properties.  When the engine asks for the value of your `performancePeriod` property you are never returning null.  The persistence engine is going to persist whatever you tell it the value of the `performancePeriod` property is.  You have muddled concerns in your domain class and the behavior that you are describing as problematic is a consequence of that.

The way you have your class written is peculiar for several reasons.  The `performancePeriod` field is never being used for anything.  I can't tell for sure from your question but it may be that part of the confusion is that you aren't making a distinction between the definition of a field and the definition of a property.

Comment: If any code ever invokes `setPerformancePeriod('someStringValue')` on an instance of your class, that value is being assigned to the `performancePeriod` String but your never use that String for anything.